# if page has class then change image wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to be able to change the logo if the page has a class, 'white' but nothing is happening when using the code below...

IS there anything here i'm doing wrong?

```
<?php 
$body_classes = get_body_class();
if(in_array('white', $body_classes))
{
echo '<img alt="Blue Moon Creative Ltd Logo" class="logomobile" src="/img/blue_moon_logo_250a-   copy1.png">'; 
} else {
 echo '<img alt="Blue Moon Creative Ltd Logo" class="logomobile" src="/img/bluemoonlogoblack.png">';
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the page? Are you positive white is a body class? Check the rendered page to confirm.

Comment: Link to the page: http://www.bluemooncreative.co.uk/shaun/services/strategic-branding-corporate-identity-4/

Comment: Well that link doesn't have a body class white, or an element with `.logomobile`, so I'm not sure how you're troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

I would use CSS with either a "child" or "descendant" selector.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="myLogo"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/*regular logo*/    
.myLogo {width:200px; height:100px; background: url('images/logo1.png') no-repeat}

/*alternate logo*/
.white .myLogo {width:200px; height:100px; background: url('images/logo2.png') no-repeat}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   <?php
    $body_classes = get_body_class('white');
    if($body_classes)
    {
    echo '<img alt="Blue Moon Creative Ltd Logo" class="logomobile" src="/img/blue_moon_logo_250a-   copy1.png">'; 
    } else {
     echo '<img alt="Blue Moon Creative Ltd Logo" class="logomobile" src="/img/bluemoonlogoblack.png">';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: He wants to check if it has that class, not add it to the current classes.

Comment: @jboneca This will return a value `TRUE` or `FALSE` if the class white exists. Know your facts. And why the downvote? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_body_class

Comment: Assuming you're being snotty because you think I downvoted you, which I didn't. Did you read at all the link you posted? Adding a parameter (which is optional, not expected) will add it to the current array of body classes. It does not check to see if a class is in the current array of body classes. Moreover, it doesn't return true or false. It returns an array.